# Writing an extension method for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, extension-methods

I would like to have an extension method called `FirstOrDefaultCache()`

> which would check
>   `dbContext.EntityName.Local.FirstOrDefault(condition)`, and only if
>   that is null, check `dbContext.EntityName.FirstOrDefault(condition)`.

I got the following from another post, which works okay:

```
public static TEntity FirstOrDefaultCache<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> queryable, 
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition) where TEntity : class
{
    return queryable
        .Local.FirstOrDefault(condition.Compile()) // find in local cache
           ?? queryable.FirstOrDefault(condition); 
          // if local cache returns null check the db
}
```

However, I cannot use this after a `.Include()`.

`dbContext.EntityName.FirstOrDefaultCache(some condition);` works, but `dbContext.EntityName.Include(x => x.NavProperty).FirstOrDefaultCache(some condition);` **does not work.**

Comment: What is the return type of the `Include()` method?  You can create another extension method that will work with that type.

Comment: That is an IQueryable<T>, however, I cannot access .Local in an IQueryable, and trying to cast it to a DbSet<T> throws an invalid cast exception at run-time.

Comment: have you tried extending IQueryable<T> instead of DbSet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  `IQueryable<T>` in order to be able to use your extension method after `Include` or `Where` or any other. But because query results are not cached, you will not be able to use `Local` in your extension.

Your options are to disable lazy loading for certain included properties to avoid `Include`

**or** you could implement some kind of second level cache for your queries. For example [this one](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/caching-the-results-of-linq-queries/), but I have not tried it and it is quite old.

you use it like this:

```
var result = q.Take(10).FromCache()
```

In your case it would probably look something  like:

```
dbContext.EntityName.Include(x => x.NavProperty).FromCache().First(condition)
```

Comment: Okay, I think I am starting to wrap my head around this now.  There are some in code situations where somet entity may either be already in the dbContext locally (because it was just added), or it was added on a previous run (different dbContext), now residing on the DB Store.  I want to have a nice one liner that would first check locally, and then check the store.